# Why System.getProperty doesn't return value from System variables in windows

Tags: java, windows, properties, system

I have this system variable

[image]

this code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("area"));
```

returns null.

Could I get acces to system variables from java code through System.getProperty method ?

P.S
[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is not a system variable but an *environment* variable. You can access these variables by using `System.getenv()`. 
`System.getProperty()` is used to return any variables set while starting the program. Example:

```
# java -Dmyproperty=myvalue MyProgram
```

Comment: System.out.println(System.getenv("area")); returns null

Comment: Notice that in java 8, you should write `java -Dmyproperty=myvalue -jar myProgram.jar` instead of `java -jar myProgram.jar -Dmyproperty=myvalue`, or `myproperty` would be `null`

Answer (score 3):

[`System#getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) gets you the system properties.

You can access the environment variables Map through [`System#getenv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29)

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("area"));
```

Should get you your results.

**EDIT:**

Try and run the following code and check if your required variable appears in the console or the behavior is incosistent for other defined variables:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> envSet = System.getenv().keySet();
        for (String env : envSet) {
            System.out.println("Env Variable : " + env + " has value : "
                    + System.getenv(env));
        }

    }
```

Comment: *System.out.println(System.getenv("area"));* returns null

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Open a *new* command prompt and type `set area`, and tell us the output.

Comment: output in cmd: * area=1 *

Comment: result was added to topic

Comment: *PopoFibo*, what do you think?

Comment: @gstackoverflow take a look at the edit and execute it to check if the variable appears, also Windows acts in weird ways which are resolved by a simple system reboot, try that maybe?!

Answer (score 0):

To list all `Java System Properties` Use, Then check if you have an `area` property:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.list(System.out);
```

See This [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-system-properties-key-and-value-in-java/)